# How to hide distinct column in sql selection

Tags: sql

I am doing a query in sql to find rows with distinct value of `name` as below:

```
select distinct name, age, sex from person
```

it works but I don't want to show the name column in the result set. Is there a way to hide this column?

**EDIT1**
the reason I put `distinct name` there is to avoid multiple rows with the same name returned. My table has person with the same name but different age and sex. So I want to make the result distinct in name but don't show the name.

Comment: don't select it then

Comment: If it's your own app doing the retrieve of the data, simply take out the code that would display it.

Comment: @vkp I need distinct to make the row distinct. Otherwise there will be mutiple rows for the same name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
select age, sex from (
   select distinct name, age, sex from person);
```

I'm presuming you might have people with the same age and sex but a different name.

Otherwise just remove the name

Comment: I have person with the same name but different age and sex. I don't want to show multiple rows with the same name

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (sql server 2016):

```
create table person (age varchar(20), [name] varchar(20), gender varchar(20))
go
insert into person values ('20', 'joe', 'm')
insert into person values ('19', 'tom', 'm')
insert into person values ('25', 'sally', 'f')
insert into person values ('28', 'Tammy', 'f')
go

select age, gender from (select distinct name, age, gender from person) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your query as a sub query here.
From your query again select age and sex alone.

```
select age, sex from (select distinct name, age, sex from person) As x
```